# SVM: decrease/increase of geometric margin after feature transformation

Tags: self-study, svm

> Consider two labeled points $(x = 1, y = 1)$ and $(x = 3, y = -1)$. Is
> the resulting geometric margin we attain in the feature space using feature vectors $\phi(x)=[x, x^2]^T$ greater then the geometric margin resulting from using the input $x$ directly?

The correct answer is yes, it is greater. Justification is that including 2nd coordinate can only increase the margin.

I understand solution for this **specific** problem as following: we can directly calculate the distance between two points before and after tranformation. After transformation this distance is larger, hence geometric margin for decision boundary (middle of the distance) is also larger.

**The question is**: can we generalize this result for any case (any given data set)? If we have some geometric margin in $d$ dimenstion, is it correct to say that  we will have greater margin in $d+1$ dimension? Because looking at formula $\gamma^{i} = \frac{y^{i} (\theta x^{i} + \theta_0)} {\mid \theta \mid}$ it is not quite obvious that $\gamma^{i}$ would be greater in higher dimensions.

Thanks in advance.